# Unable to simplify a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to follow the steps for simplifying the system of equations presented below - but for some reason I'm not getting the same result that the book is getting.

[image]

$$v = x^2 + y^2 - 2xycos\alpha_{u, v}$$

Plugging it into the first equation...

$$(1-a)y^2 - ax^2 - 2ycos\alpha_{v, w} + 2axycos\alpha_{u, v} + 1 = 0$$

I'm not sure how to simplify this further to get the cosine terms they use in what they call the "Simplified P3P system".

Comment: can you say something about the variables?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sure, there is more context in this page (where I got the equations from). I'd be happy to paste the information in my original post, but I figure this link will be easier to follow: http://iplimage.com/blog/p3p-perspective-point-overview/

Comment: what are the solving variables?

Comment: The solving variables are $x$ and $y$. We assume the knowledge of the rest of the variables. (An aside: is this system really linear since we are dealing with squares of variables?)

Comment: no the system is not linear since we have $$x^2,y^2$$

Comment: @Carpetfizz your work seems right to me... the post you're referencing does seem to be missing a 2 in front of the cosines.

Answer (score 1):

solving the first wo equation s for $x,y$ we get
$$x=1/2\,{\frac {av-bv+2\, \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right) +\sqrt {
 \left( \cos \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2}+av-1} \right) \cos
 \left( \alpha \right) }{\cos \left( \beta \right) }}
$$
$$y=\cos \left( \alpha \right) +\sqrt { \left( \cos \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+av-1}
$$
plug this in the third equation and you will get a condition that these equations fulfill the third equation